# Merge Duplicate values with in a single array while json parsing in iOS

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, merge

I want to parse json and keep it in the local array so that I can display the data as like excell in my app. The json is redundant. I have uploaded an image for your kind consideration.
Here is my json

```
    [
  {
    "date": "2018-10-21",
    "Status": "Confirmed",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-22",
    "Status": "Confirmed",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-22",
    "Status": "Delivered",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-22",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-22",
    "Status": "Rejected",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-22",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-22",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-23",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-23",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "3"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-24",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-25",
    "Status": "Delivered",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-25",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-26",
    "Status": "Delivered",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-27",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "3"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-27",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-27",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-28",
    "Status": "Confirmed",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-28",
    "Status": "Delivered",
    "Orders": "3"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-29",
    "Status": "Delivered",
    "Orders": "5"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-29",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-29",
    "Status": "Rejected",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-29",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-31",
    "Status": "Confirmed",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-31",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-31",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-10-31",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-01",
    "Status": "Confirmed",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-01",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-01",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "2"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-01",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-02",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-03",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "4"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-03",
    "Status": "Cancelled",
    "Orders": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-11-04",
    "Status": "Processing",
    "Orders": "1"
  }
]
```

After parsing it I want to keep the data of same date together. For example for a particular date like 2018-10-20 I would like to keep all the information in an entity class so that I can populate the information in the table.

[image]

My parsing code is provided below

```
    -(void)parseLocalJson
{
    resultsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Results" ofType:@"json"];
    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSArray *jsonArr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    for(int r =0;r<[jsonArr count];)
    {
        id val=[jsonArr objectAtIndex:r];
        Results* prevResult;
        //Results* aResult;
        Results* aResult=[[Results alloc]init];
        aResult.date=[val valueForKey:@"date"];


         if(![aResult.date isEqualToString:prevResult.date])
        {
             //Results* aResult=[[Results alloc]init];
            NSString* status=[val valueForKey:@"Status"];
            NSString* orders=[val valueForKey:@"Orders"];
            if([status isEqualToString:@"Confirmed"])
            {
                aResult.orderStatus_Confirmed=orders;
            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Delivered"])
            {
                aResult.orderStatus_Delivered=orders;
            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Cancelled"])
            {
                aResult.orderStatus_Cancelled=orders;

            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Rejected"])
            {
                aResult.orderStatus_Rejected=orders;
            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Pending"])
            {
                aResult.orderStatus_Pending=orders;
            }
            [resultsArray addObject:aResult];
            r++;
        }
        else
        {
            r--;
            NSString* status=[val valueForKey:@"Status"];
            NSString* orders=[val valueForKey:@"Orders"];
            if([status isEqualToString:@"Confirmed"])
            {
                prevResult.orderStatus_Confirmed=orders;
            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Delivered"])
            {
                prevResult.orderStatus_Delivered=orders;
            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Cancelled"])
            {
                prevResult.orderStatus_Cancelled=orders;

            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Rejected"])
            {
                prevResult.orderStatus_Rejected=orders;
            }
            else if([status isEqualToString:@"Pending"])
            {
                prevResult.orderStatus_Pending=orders;
            }

            //[resultsArray addObject:prevResult];

        }
        prevResult=aResult;




    }





    // Parse the string into JSON
    //NSDictionary *json = [myJSON JSONValue];
}
```

I want to keep data in my array according to the image provided.  Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You **need** to help people help you. What problems have you found with your code? What have you tried to solve them? What is the type `Results`? Etc. Edit your question to provide this information (don't try to add it in comments) and someone will undoubtedly help you along.

Comment: @CRD my code outcome is the resultArray consisting all the  34 objects of the json. But resultArray have to be the number of objects according to unique date

Comment: You have been on SO for 5yrs, an iOS developer for 6yrs, you know how debugging and SO work. What have **you** tried to debug your issue? What did you find? Explain why you are stuck by **editing the question**, and someone will undoubtedly be more than happy to help you out.